Applying of Sobolev Trace Theorem

THEOREM 1 (Trace Theorem). Assume $U$ is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Then there exists a bounded linear operator
$$
T: W^{1, p}(U) \rightarrow L^p(\partial U)
$$
such that
(i) $T u=\left.u\right|_{\partial U}$ if $u \in W^{1, p}(U) \cap C(\bar{U})$ and
(ii) $\|T u\|_{L^p(\partial U)} \leq C\|u\|_{W^{1, p}(U)}$,
for each $u \in W^{1, p}(U)$, with the constant $C$ depending only on $p$ and $U$.

Someone said that the following conclusion can be proved by using Trace Theorem. But I cannot understand that because $H^s(\mathbb R^n)\not\subset W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ and $H^{s-\frac12}(\mathbb R^{n-1})\not\subset L^p(\mathbb R^{n-1})$.

We define trace operator: $T_rf(x,y)=f(0,y)$ $(y \in \mathbb R^{n-1}).$ Let $s>\frac{1}{2}$. Then $T_r:H^{s}(\mathbb R^n) \to H^{s-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb R^{n-1})$ with the norm inequality $$\|T_rf(x,y)\|_{H^{s-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb R^{n-1})} \leq C \|f(x,y)\|_{H^{s}(\mathbb R^n)}$$

So how can I use the Trace Theorem to prove that? (I'm a beginner of Sobolev Space, so maybe this question is a bit basic. If the above content is the conclusion of a textbook, please tell me the title of the book so that I can study this part by myself. Thanks!)

$\color{red}{\textbf{UPDATE}}$
Thanks for the comments and I know the second theorem is stronger than the first one. But I still cannot understand how to use the second one to prove the first one. I mean, where is "$s-\frac12$" in the first theorem?

The second claim is a stronger version of the trace theorem above it, so you cannot use the above theorem to prove the one below.

@daw, well, I saw the first theorem from Partial Differential Equations by Evans. Can you tell me one of textbook including the second theorem?

In Fourier variable, the trace operator becomes $\hat{f}\mapsto\int_{\mathbb R} \hat{f}(\xi_0, \xi') d\xi_0$ (up to a constant factor).
Then by Cauchy-Schwarz, denoting $\xi=(\xi_0,\xi')\in{\mathbb R}\times{\mathbb R^{n-1}}$ the Fourier variable,
\begin{equation}
\left|\int_{\mathbb R} \hat{f}(\xi_0, \xi') d\xi_0\right|^2\le\int_{\mathbb R} (1+\xi^2)^s |\hat{f}(\xi_0, \xi')|^2 d\xi_0 \int_{\mathbb R}(1+\xi'^2+\xi_0^2)^{-s}d\xi_0
\end{equation}
In the last integral, the substitution $\xi_0=t\sqrt{1+ \xi'^2}$ gives
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb R}(1+\xi'^2+\xi_0^2)^{-s}d\xi_0
=(1+\xi'^2)^{-s+\frac{1}{2}}\int_{\mathbb R}(1+t^2)^{-s}d t
\end{equation}
It follows that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}}(1+\xi'^2)^{s-\frac{1}{2}}\left|\int_{\mathbb R} \hat{f}(\xi_0, \xi') d\xi_0\right|^2 d\xi'\le C_s \int_{\mathbb R^n}(1+\xi^2)^s |\hat{f}|^2d \xi
\end{equation}
which proves the trace theorem in $H^s({\mathbb R^n})$.

Thank you for the proof. And I want to ask the relationship between this theorem and above one. Can I derive the above one from this one?
